# How to read .vtu files?

Tags: image-processing, import

I see the `Import` function can import `.vtk` files. But how about `.vtu` files? Is there an existing package for this?

Comment: Import["filename.vtk"]

Comment: @DanielHuber Thanks for the comment but I want to import .vtu files.

Comment: @H.Zhou what's the issue with `Import["filename.vtu"]`?

Comment: @bmf The file will be then imported as plain text.